# How to add ChartKick chart as Mailer attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5.2, chartkick

The newer version of Chartkick has a download option that displays a button over the javascript chart, when clicked will open a new browser window and render the chart as an image.  This is great.  However, that method does not seem to help render an image to use as an email attachment.  Unless there is a way to call/render the chart using a chartkick method inside the mailer, grab the image and attach it...As far as I can tell, this functionality does not exist.

Anyone know of a way to attach a chartkick chart as an image email attachment?

Answer (score 0):

Natively? No. Chartkick performs a download using their script chartkick.js and chart.bundle.js. It happens entirely client-side, not server-side. And it should not be opening a new window. It should just download the file directly onto the client's machine. Example here: https://chartkick.com/react

Comment: Evidently, Safari will it open a new window.  Sure would be nice to attach a chart via mailer.  Thanks!